# mysql return default row if no row is found

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like this

```
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | attr      | value  |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | attr1     | val1   |
|  2 | attr1     | val2   |
|  2 | default   | val3   |
|  3 | default   | val4   |
+----+-----------+--------+
```

Here, (id, attr) is the primary key. Also, id (int), attr (varchar), value (varchar).

I want to design a query such that for all distinct values of id I can fetch value of a specific attribute, and if it is not present for that attribute but is present as default value then return that default value.
i_e result above table, for attr1 will be

```
+----+--------+
| id | value  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | val1   |
|  2 | val2   |
|  3 | val4   |
+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by combining two queries with a `UNION`.

The first query fetches the results for the given attribute, and the second query fetches the default results for IDs that do not have the given attribute.

For example:

```
select id, value 
from your_table
where attr = 'attr1'
union 
select t1.id, t1.value 
from your_table t1
where t1.attr = 'default'
and not exists (select NULL from your_table t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.attr = 'attr1')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL, attr VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,value  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id,attr));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1 ,'attr1','val1'),
(2 ,'attr1','val2'),
(2 ,'default','val3'),
(3 ,'default','val4');

SELECT DISTINCT a.id
              , COALESCE(b.value,a.value) value
           FROM my_table a 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table b 
             ON b.id = a.id 
            AND b.attr = 'attr1';

+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | val1  |
|  2 | val2  |
|  3 | val4  |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: yeah, but that is the use case, I want a specific attribute, so I am going to provide that attribute. If that attribute doesnot have a value, and a default values is present it should give me a default value.

Comment: Doesn't work. Do an `INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (4, 'attr2', 'val5');` and then try the query again. You will notice `(4, val5)` in the result. Then do `INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (4, 'default', 'val6');`, now you will even get *two* result for id=4. Adding `AND a.attr = 'default'` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to find row with max id in default attr and rest all as such

```
select t1.*
from t t1 inner join (
    select attr, max(id) id
    from t
    group by attr
) t2 on t1.attr = t2.attr
and case when t1.attr = 'default' then t2.id else t1.id end = t1.id;
```

Comment: this does not work, if there are multiple default values. Eg: `(1, 'attr1', 'val1'  ),(2, 'attr1', 'val2'  ),(2, 'default', 'val3'),(3, 'default', 'val4'),(4, 'default', 'val5');`
It does not give the id 3

Comment: @Potato_head Ah I see.